# rxjs6 Piping two observables gives subscribe is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, observable, rxjs6

rxjs 6.2.1

I'm getting `ClusterStreams__.a.subscribe is not a function`

I'm trying to pipe the results of `getClusterArns()` into `describeClusters()` with the below code ...

```
function getClusterArns() {
        const ecs = new AWS.ECS();
        return ecs.listClusters().promise();
}

function describeClusters(clusterArns) {
    const params = { clusters: clusterArns };
        const ecs = new AWS.ECS();
        return ecs.describeClusters(params).promise();
}


export const ClusterArnStream = from(getClusterArns());
export const ClusterStream = pipe(
  combineLatest(ClusterArnStream),
  mergeMap(([_, clusterArnsResponse]) => describeClusters(clusterArnsResponse.clusterArns)),
  map(x => x.clusters),
  multicast(() => new ReplaySubject(1))
);
```